# How to open a specific activity from an external link clicking

Tags: java, android

I know this question is not new, but its a bit different from already asked questions. I have a website that provides links to my app. The links direct users to specific data on my app. This is the layout of my app: I have 4 activities as Activity1.class, Activity2.class, Activity3.class, and of course the MainActivity.class which is the launcher activity.

My worry is this: On my website, I have 3 buttons: button 1 goes to open directly Activity1 on my app (assuming the app is already installed on the device), Button 2 on website opens Activity2 in my app.

> Note: the app and the website are not by any means linked.

My question is: how to get a URL link to specific activity on my app. I need 3 URLs that open different 3 activities. I need these links for external use, such that they open a specified activity whey clicked.

Something like: http://myapppackage/ACTIVITY1.

This is just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you AndroidManifest.xml add intent-filters to the activities like this

```
   <activity android:name=".ACTIVITY1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="myapppackage"
                android:pathPattern="/ACTIVITY1" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ACTIVITY2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="myapppackage"
                android:pathPattern="/ACTIVITY2" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>   

     <activity android:name=".ACTIVITY3">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="myapppackage"
                android:pathPattern="/ACTIVITY3" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

For more info check this out

> [Deep Linking In Android](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

Comment: Ok thank you for the suggestions, so how would the link look like when i add these to manifest?

Comment: Same it will look like http://myapppackage/ACTIVITY1 this replace ACTIVITY2 and ACTIVITY3

Comment: You mean for example if my package name is com.myapp.myfirstapp the link would then be: http://com.myapp.myfirstapp/Activity1 and I can actually take this link and place it on my website button such that someone who clicks the button from the website can actually open my app direct to Activity1 (assuming the app is already installed)???

Comment: In that case there is host attribute in every data elelment replace host give your package name for that value in this example replace myapppackage with com.myapp.myfirstapp

Comment: Thank you all fine you helped